# PowerBI calculating Last years Sales to date figures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get last years sales TD figures from my SalesData datatable. Sadly the column just shows total sales when brought into the table. Here is the Formula. I've looked at various examples etc, none seem to work!

```
VALUE PYTD = 
VAR pytddate1 = DATEADD(DATEADD(DATEADD(ENDOFYEAR('FiscalCalendar'[Date].[Date]),-1,YEAR),1,DAY),-1,YEAR)
VAR pytddate2 = DATEADD(ENDOFMONTH('FiscalCalendar'[Date].[Date]),-1,YEAR)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
SUM(SalesData[val]),
FILTER(
    ALL('FiscalCalendar'[Date].[Date]),
     'FiscalCalendar'[Date].[Date]
        >= pytddate1  && 'FiscalCalendar'[Date].[Date] <= pytddate2
)    
)
```

it's seems fairly straight forward but it's just not playing ball for me it seems. Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are complicating things a bit by the variables and the all-function. Have a look at this post, it might be helpful: 
[YTD sum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892000/dax-last-year-to-date/54909061#54909061)

Cheers,

Oscar

Comment: That is the solution. Worked first time. Many thanks

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers!